# c# add record to selected customer

Tags: c#, sql

[home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjNNn.png)

[custumers screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MttR.png)

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EjfB.png)

hi. first of all sorry my bad english.
I want to make a technical service program. custumers part is done. but when i add device on customer i am little confused. i want to add device when i selected customer. i am using sql. i hope i can explain myself. thx

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not images (or links to images.) Also show us your current code attempt.

Comment: Look at [ask] to see ways you can improve your question. Better questions get better answers.